# Как запустить скрипт через определенное время?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Есть скрипт, который перенаправляет пользователей на другой сайт если у них включен блокировщик рекламы. Но он срабатывает до того как реклама про грузиться на странице. Как сделать выполнение этого скрипта через скажем 10 секунд? Сам скрипт :  `<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function(){ if (jQuery('#solnisko111').height() == 0) { window.location = 'https://www.google.ru/'; } });</script>`

Comment: В том то и дело Если я это знак как сделать Я бы сюда не пришел )))) Покажите как это сделать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

таймаут задается в миллисекундах

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (jQuery('#solnisko111').height() == 0) { 
        window.location = 'https://www.google.ru/'; 
    } 
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Спасибо работает ))))

Comment: @Helpsetup всегда пожалуйста